# mongoDB conditional increment

Tags: mongodb

```js
db.posts.update({_id: post._id},
{
 $inc: {likes: 1},
 $addToSet:{likedby: johnny._id}
})
```

So $addToSet will only add the id to the array if the id doesn't already exist in the array, but then my likes are getting incremented either way.

Is there any way I can make this increment conditional?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35752144/inc-only-when-addtoset-successful Answer found here.

Answer (score 2):

Query

- search based on id and if not exists
- if found means not exists so update, with no need for `$addToSet`
- replace 1 with `post._id` and "c" with `johnny._id`

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/i3fRGVcHj3f)

```js
db.collection.update({
  "_id": 1,
  "likedby": {
    "$ne": "c"
  }
},
{
  "$inc": {
    "likes": 1
  },
  "$push": {
    "likedby": "c"
  }
})
```